# Chartjs with Typescript: The types of 'interaction.mode' are incompatible between these types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I want to create a **React Functional Component** with Typescript that displays a **chart using chartjs**.

My parent passes options and data to the child component that renders the line chart.

When trying to pass the options object I get the following typescript error:

```
The types of 'interaction.mode' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"index" | "dataset" | "point" | "nearest" | "x" | "y" | undefined'.
```

Which is weird because my options look like this:

```
const options = {
    ...
    interaction: {
        ...
        mode: "index"
    },
    ...
}
```

Why is `"index"` not assignable to `"index" | ...`?

I tried to recreate the error in stackblitz and although the error don't pop up in the preview it still seem to occur:
[image: Error message from stackblitz]

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-muu2g3?file=src%2FExample.tsx)

Answer (score 2):

When I change my options to

```
const options = {
    ...
    interaction: {
        ...
        mode: "index" as "index"
    },
    ...
}
```

it does work

Answer (score 0):

You need to define type of options:

```
  import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';

  const options: ChartOptions = {
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
    },
  };
```